# Azure Custom Domain billing

Tags: azure, billing

I have purchased a domain on Azure.

Azure domains are billed per year. My billing info says that this billing period (this month) I have spent the amount of the domain cost.

But there is also I prediction of billing. It says that in the next month I would pay the same amount again.

Am I really going to pay this amount again next month ?

Comment: There are several options to buy a domain on Azure. How did you purchase it?

Comment: In Custom Domain manager I added a new domain and paid the amount. That is all I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to pay for the domain next month.

Billing cost prediction is calculated only using what we purchased this month. The prediction does not mean you will pay them next month.

In other words, they predict you will purchase another custom domain next month.